# How to cover CurrencyType object in test class?

Tags: apex, code-coverage, currencytype

I am updating the "conversion rate" on the CurrencyType object daily using batch class. But while writing test class unable to insert CurrencyType. This is because of CurrencyType object DML operation not allowed. Please suggest the way how I can cover this is in the test class. Thanks In advance!

Below Is the  Batch Class:

```
global class  updateCurrencyBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts {
    String batchQuery='';
    List<CurrencyType> localscope = new List<CurrencyType>();
    List<Exchange_Rate__c> ctlist = new List<Exchange_Rate__c>();
    Map<String,Double> updateRateMap = new Map<String,Double>();
    global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        system.debug('***Start Method');                    
        batchQuery = 'Select  id,IsoCode From CurrencyType where isActive=true AND IsoCode!=\'INR\'';              
        return Database.getQueryLocator(batchQuery);    
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<CurrencyType> Scope) {
        localscope=Scope;
        ctlist =[SELECT  FromCurrency__c,ExchangeRate__c FROM Exchange_Rate__c];
        for(Exchange_Rate__c et : ctlist){
            updateRateMap.put(et.FromCurrency__c,Double.ValueOf(et.ExchangeRate__c));
        }
        for(CurrencyType ct : localScope){                          
            String id=ct.id;                          
            String str = String.valueOf(ct.IsoCode);
            Double val = Double.valueOf(updateRateMap.get(ct.IsoCode));
            //Double val = 1/vall;
            system.debug('***Isocode:'+str);                       
            system.debug('***rate:'+(1/val));
            Http h = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/CurrencyType/'+id+'?_HttpMethod=PATCH');
            Map<String,double> mapstrBydouble=new Map<String,double>();
            mapstrBydouble.put('ConversionRate',(1/val));
            String body=JSON.serialize(mapstrBydouble);
            system.debug('body'+JSON.serialize(mapstrBydouble));
            req.setBody(body);  
            req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setMethod('POST');
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {       
    }  
}
```

====================================================================

And my Test class :

```
@isTest 
public class Test_updateCurrencyBatch 
{
    static testMethod void testMethod1() 
    {
        CurrencyType[] curr= new CurrencyType();
        curr.ConversionRate=46.3;
        curr.IsoCode='AUD';
        curr.IsActive=true;
        curr.IsCorporate=false;
        insert curr;

        Exchange_Rate__c ec = new Exchange_Rate__c();

        ec.FromCurrency__c ='AUD';
        ec.ExchangeRate__c =46.3;

        insert ec;

        Test.startTest();

        updateCurrencyBatch obj = new updateCurrencyBatch();
        test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class,  new updateCurrencyBatchMockClass());
        DataBase.executeBatch(obj); 

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Rahul For your response. I already see that but no use. Actually I got DML Not allowed on CurrencyType  error while running the test class.

Comment: Please check the answer by Cropredy

Comment: Thanks, Rahul. Its help to resolve the problem.